# Disable edit of specific cell DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is it possible to only disable the edit of a specific cell (by column- and rowindex) using RShiny DT?

E.g. in the next code sample, only the cell which contains 'Mary' should be disabled.
All other cells should be editable.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Sample data (you can replace this with your own dataset)
dat <- data.frame(
  userName = c("John", "Mary", "Mike"),
  start = c("06/08/2019", "01/01/2019", "23/10/2019"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Editable Datatable Example"),
  DTOutput("userTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$userTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, editable = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$userTable_cell_edit, {
    # Handle cell edits here (e.g., update the underlying data)
    # For demonstration purposes, we'll just print the edited value
    cat("Edited value:", input$userTable_cell_edit$value, "\n")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Not possible with the built-in features. But maybe a terrible hack could allow this, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

One of these hacks would be to add an event handler listening on `dblclick` on the specific cell which stops the event from reaching the handler which fires the edit dialogue:

```r
datatable(dat, 
         editable = TRUE, 
         rownames = FALSE,
         options = 
           list(
             columnDefs = 
               list(
                 list(
                   targets = 0, 
                   createdCell = 
                     JS("function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                           if (row == 1) {
                             $(td).on('dblclick', function(e) {
                               e.stopPropagation()
                             })
                           }
                         }")
                 )
               )
           )
)
```

It is a very fragile hack (especially because it only prevents double clicks and does not switch off editing *per se*, that is if there is any other method to edit the cell this is **not** prevented with this hack) and you should think carefully how to address the cell properly. I used `createCell` in `columnDefs` to add the event handler. It is important that you add the listener somewhere **below** `<table>`, because there the edit handler sits. So we want to attach a listener below to be able to prevent the event from bubbling up.

To make a long story short, there are a plethora of reasons why you should **not** use this hack, but it can be done at least.